# OpendID Connect and IDP Initiated SSO

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, openid-connect

I have an application which is a Service Provider. 
Is it possible to implement an Idp initiated SSO with OpenID Connect?
It looks like for Idp initiated SSO only SAML could be used, is that correct?  Or is there a way to make OpenID Connect work as well?
I'm thinking of using some open source tools like Keycloak or OneLogin toolkit etc..

Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes - technically IDP-Initiated is a SAML term (in the sense that it is described in the SAML spec). As @Wiktor says, you are on your own with OIDC.

Answer (score 9):

Secure IDP-initiated-SSO is not possible with OpenID Connect in its current form. There is however a feature called 3rd-party-initiated-SSO which allows for launching the authentication process via a 3rd-party but that still visits the RP first.

Here are details about third-party initiated SSO:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ThirdPartyInitiatedLogin

As to the IDP-init suggestions described: a well-behaved RP should prevent this from happening - as technically it enables CSRF - by using the `state` parameter or (as a less-preferred and less-secure solution) by keeping request state in a cookie which makes the RP vulnerable to CSRF only during the request/response roundtrip.

There's a work-in-progress that describes - amongst other things - how true IDP-init-SSO can be achieved with an extension to OpenID Connect in a secure way using a signed message: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bradley-oauth-jwt-encoded-state#section-4.3

Answer (score 8):

Since OpenIDConnect is OAuth2 based, the IdP initiated SSO should technically be possible but under one condition - the SP doesn't rely on the state passed down to the IdP in the intial request where the state acts like an *anti-forgery token* (i.e. upon the return request the returning state is compared to the state sent by the SP in the initial request).

The longer answer would be:

The first step of the **authorization code** OAuth2 flow is the SP redirecting to the IdP and the IdP redirects back with the one time code. The `state` parameter is often passed by the SP and the SP expects the state be passed back.

There are two cases.

The SP verifies the state (e.g. compares it to the state stored in a temp cookie). The IdP SSO won't work as there is no way the IdP knows/forges the state and thus it cannot issue a valid request to the SP that would act as the IdP initiated SSO.

The SP doesn't verify the state. The IdP can then issue the *response* to a regular OAuth2 request but without the actual request, i.e. it redirects to

```
 https://sp.com/oauth2?code=...authcode
```

and the SP picks the OAuth2 handhshake from there as if it was the SP to first initiate the handshake.

In other words, whether the IdP initiated SSO is possible, it only depends on the SP. Since the [spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) **recommends** using `state` to prevent such behavior (classified there as CSRF), I believe you are on your own here. Also, read more on possible security issues around the `state` parameter.

> 3.1.2.1.  Authentication Request […] state - RECOMMENDED. Opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback. Typically, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF, XSRF) mitigation is done by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.  I will have to digest this as I'm not an SSO expert. I may have more questions later.  Thanks again.

Comment: So let me rephrase this.  If I have a situation where a user first logs in to their organizational portal, authenticates to their IDP and then clicks a link to go to my application, then the best way to facilitate this would be via SAML?  To me this scenario is an IDP initiated login and you are saying this could really only be accomplished via SAML.  If I was to use OpenID Connect, the user would have to go directly to my application which in turn would redirect to their IDP going through an SP initiated authentication/authorization flow.   Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need the IdP initiated login for this, neither you need SAML. You just redirect to any page in your app that requires authentication. The app kicks the user out, to the IdP, according to the protocol. Are you really sure you understood what the IdP initiated SSO is used for? It's not for usual scenarios where users "click a link" but rather for scenarios where "users don't click anything and still the IdP should be able to use SP resources for some reason".

Comment: My understanding of IdP initiated SSO is that the user is already logged in when he clicks on a link to be redirected to my application.  That means that when the application kicks the user out and back to the IdP, IdP will know that the user is already logged in.  It seems that there will be a cookie passed back and forth to let IdP know that the user doesn't need to be presented with a login screen.  But i'm not sure if something special needs to be configured on the Idp and/or SP end to perform the choreography with an authenticated user.  I guess that's where I lack understanding...

Comment: Yes, sounds like you lack the understanding. The cookie is not passed back and forth. Rather, the IdP maintains a private cookie that establishes a session, once the user is logged in once, they don't need to authenticate again. If another SP comes with a **regular** OpenID flow, the authentication endpoint answers **without redirecting to the login page**. Thus, you don't need the IdP initiated SSO to not to show login screens over and over once users logged in once.