# Azure AD B2C - Federated SAML IDP Initiated Sign-In

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have configured our web application to utilise Azure AD B2C via OIDC, which works successfully with built-in IDP integrations like Github or Local Accounts. We've had a customer request to integrate their SAML IDP into our B2C tenant. Using a custom policy within B2C, this works well with the user being sent from the web application to B2C, then on to the SAML IDP.

The new request, however, is for IDP-initiated sign-in, where the IDP sends us the SAML assertion to automatically log users in. So far our efforts have led to the user being redirected back to B2C with a SAML assertion, but B2C cannot go any further. Ultimately, we need this SAML assertion to be converted to an OIDC token that can be sent back to our web application to handle the last part of the user flow. Based on previous answers in the SO community, and B2C articles, this appears not to be supported within B2C.

My questions are:

- Surely other businesses must have encountered this need, as IDP-initiated sign-in is part of the SAML standard. How have they solved it?
- Is our attempted solution valid, or should we consider removing B2C from our infrastructure? Is there an alternative?
- Could a viable alternative be to configure our web application to support SAML as well as OIDC? I found a potential reference for this option [here](https://gist.github.com/rbrayb/98bf63a059b11c0a8d426cb1aba04925).

Here's the error message we receive from Azure AD B2C when trying to process the SAML assertion:

> Policy 'B2C_1A_MockSAMLSOO' in tenant '*****.onmicrosoft.com' does not have a supported relying party protocol

And here's our current relying party:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CustomSignUpOrSignIn" />
  <Endpoints>
    <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
    <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
  </Endpoints>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emails" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />

    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Answer (score 0):

The OIDC standard does not support IDP initiated flows, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050353/opendid-connect-and-idp-initiated-sso). When using IDP initiated, neither the client nor the OIDC provider can easily determine that the user initiated the flow, or detect whether a response is unsolicited.

These days, rather than use IDP initiated, it is recommended to get partners to bookmark links to the OIDC secured app, along with a hint to tell the app to use the SAML IDP as part of its authentication flow. When the app runs its (SP initiated) OIDC code flow it can then use a parameter such as `acr_values` or `idp` to ensure that the SAML IDP is used.

```
https://www.example.com?acr_values=saml_partner1_idp
```

OAuth and OIDC tend to provide the [most up to date standards](https://openid.net/developers/specs/) for applications, so I would aim to avoid SAML integration into the app if you can. Instead, the OIDC provider should initiate all forms of authentication for you, then issue consistent tokens to the app.

**HOW TO PROCEED?**

The requirement is probably from an IT department at the customer, based on how they link to other apps, as opposed to being a requirement with business value. I would aim to convince them to bookmark a different URL based on that being standard and providing best security for their data when using the latest security standards.

**TACTICAL SOLUTIONS**

The problem with any OIDC coded solution is that it is likely to decrease the security of the app, or add technical costs. If I had to implement such a solution I would look into the extensibility / plugin model of the OIDC provider.

I would perhaps aim to follow a nonce pattern, where the OIDC provider receives the IDP initiated SAML response and stores data in a nonces table. It then returns a short lived and unguessable number that can only be used once to the app:

```
https://www.example.com?nonce=OFiicYQJYY2phWnD5nFMflid5Du82ycW
```

The app could then initiate a code flow that is as standard as possible in OIDC terms, and therefore the app should continue to perform well in PEN tests. This request would use a custom authentication method that looks up the nonce and its expiry in the nonces table. If it is valid then an OAuth delegation would be created for the user in the SAML assertion, and tokens issued to the app in the standard way.

```
https://login.example.com/oauth/authorize
    ?client_id=web-client
    &redirect_uri=https://www.example.com
    &response_type=code
    &code_challenge=l9QIPE4TFgW2y7STZDSWQ4Y4CQp
    &code_challenge_method=S256
    &state=NlAoISfdL1DxPdNGFBljlVuB
    &scope=openid%20profile
    &login_hint_token=OFiicYQJYY2phWnD5nFMflid5Du82ycW
    &acr_values=nonce_authentication
    &prompt=login
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. Unfortunately, the IDP initiated flow is a requirement from the customer. Although, I do wonder whether we could state that they redirect to an endpoint on the app, but all that does is ignores the SAML assertion and kicks into the OIDC flow whereby they should already be authenticated on the SAML IDP?

Comment: I understand - sometimes such requests from important customers are difficult to influence. I expanded on my answer, though I doubt it will provide you with a working solution unfortunately.

Comment: So in our use-case, where AD B2C is our OIDC provider, the IDP-initiated SAML assertion would be sent to AD B2C and stored (somehow) against a unique key (nonce), the user would then be redirected to the app with the key where the app starts the OIDC flow with the unique key. Upon receiving this in AD B2C, it would look up the SAML assertion that was stored against the key and generate a token without redirecting to the IDP but use the values from the SAML assertion to populate the token? I'm not entirely sure that AD B2C is going to give us that level of flexibility, unfortunately